profiles.yml is NOT FOUND
Configuration:
23:33:02    profiles.yml file [ERROR not found]
23:33:02    dbt_project.yml file [OK found and valid]
23:33:02  Required dependencies:
23:33:02   - git [OK found]

In DBT , while i am using dbt debug, I keep getting this error and when i go to my users/<my_user_id>/.dbt, The profiles.yml file exists. But still I keep getting this error in DBT CORE. Please help!
The IDE I am using is VScode.
I have tried reading everything and the documentation but this keeps happening. What do I do?
Connection test skipped since no profile was found
23:11:50  1 check failed:
23:11:50  dbt looked for a profiles.yml file in ~/.dbt/profiles.yml, but did not find one.

When I go I find it. What do I do? Please help!

Welcome to stack overflow! Could I ask how you are running dbt? Is that an error appearing in your IDE console log, for example? Are you using sudo, or running dbt as another user?

what happens if you run open ~/.dbt from your terminal?
